# REACT.JS State reset on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to set up a Sudoku app based on umd-sudoku npm package. The basic functions are: check, new game, reset the board, show answers. I tried to display the correctness of a tile through

```
<input className={(props.correct == "true" ? "" : styles.Tile)}>
```

However, the problem is that if I try to set a new game, the booleans stay on the indexed tile.
The initialBoard variable stands for the board that is actually rendered through the npm package, the board is the variable holding user's answers, which is why I thought that through initialState and setState I will be able to access the initial state.

This is the App.js part of code:

```
      class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            const initialBoard = sudoku.generate("easy", false);
            const correctAnswers = initialBoard.split("").map(() => true);
            this.state = {
              initialBoard,
              board: initialBoard,
              correctAnswers
            }
          };

          handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          };

          updateInput(event, index) {
            const tile = event.target.value ? event.target.value[0] : ".";
            this.setState((prev) => ({
              board: prev.board.slice(0, index) + tile.toString() + prev.board.slice(index + 1)
            }));
            event.preventDefault();
          };

          checkIfCorrect() {
            const solution = sudoku.solve(this.state.initialBoard).split("");
            const answer = this.state.board.split("");
            const correctAnswers = answer.map((item, key) => item == solution[key]);

            this.setState({
              correctAnswers
            });
          };

          solveBoard() {
            this.setState({
              board: sudoku.solve(this.state.initialBoard)
            });
          };

          resetBoard() {
            this.setState({
              board: this.state.initialBoard,
            });
            console.log(this.state.correctAnswers);
          };

          newBoard() {
            const initialBoard = sudoku.generate("easy", false);

            this.setState({
              initialBoard: initialBoard,
              board: initialBoard,
            });
          };
render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.App}>
        <h1>Sudoku</h1>
        <Board
          board={this.state.board}
          initialBoard={this.state.initialBoard}
          fill={this.updateInput.bind(this)}
          correctAnswers={this.state.correctAnswers}
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
        />
        <div className="buttons">
          <button onClick={this.checkIfCorrect.bind(this)}>Check</button>
          <button onClick={this.newBoard.bind(this)}>New game</button>
          <button onClick={this.solveBoard.bind(this)}>Solve</button>
          <button onClick={this.resetBoard.bind(this)}>Restart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I would be grateful for any kind of tip!

Comment: I think you have to reset the correctAnswers when you're starting a new game ?

Comment: in your `resetBoard` method what is `console.log(this.state.correctAnswers);` showing you?

Where is your render method??

Comment: @benjaminRampon I did think of that, though in this case I was wondering what is the opposite of null?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Sorry, for some reason I did not copy the render part, I updated my post. The console log tells me: "false, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, true, true...]" until it makes for the 81 tiles.

Comment: Sorry, i guess what i was trying to ask was, when you `console.log(this.state.correctAnswers)` - Are you seeing what you expect to see?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh, not really, when I reset I would like to have all elements set on true, so that the app does not validate the inputs yet

Comment: Perhaps make a method called `getInitialBoard` that just returns `sudoku.generate("easy", false)` and then within your reset `setState` set board to `board: this.getInitialBoard()` see if that helps. I feel maybe your initial board prop within the state is being overwritten somewhere...

Comment: This did not work, however I found the solution. Benjamin Rampton told to me to reset correctAnswers and following this I mapped the correctAnswers variable so that the boolean is true.

Comment: But I'm very grateful anyway, have a nice day!